# Bivariate Dist Study Question Help - determine joint PMF and P( ... )

Tags: self-study, density-function, joint-distribution, bivariate

I am in a prob. models class. Current module is on Bivariate and Multivariate Distributions.  The question below has me stumped though.  It is from a study guide and I would like to know the answer because I feel it is good to know this as it is on the higher end of complexity for this class.

So I usually approach these by drawing a graph and plotting the support points. Then plot other values when I have a bivariate discrete like this problem.  For example I had a problem that asked from a well shuffled deck, draw 2, let X = # of Ace and let Y = # of face card. So x = 0,1,2 and y = 0,1,2 and x+y <= 2. No problem getting the join PDF for that one.

For the problem below, I am stuck on how to plot points besides the support points and the join PDF because of this curve ball (for me anyway): "...Then all slips numbered less than X are removed..."  Before bivariate and multivariate modules, when I saw "are removed" by Hypergeometic Spidey-sense started tiggling. For this one, I have a slight intuition of what I want to do to solve it, but have 0% understanding of how to implement/translate into an actual join PDF that I can use to solve the Probabilty part (2).

Thanks for any direction or even a link to a similar problem that has the solution that I can review to grasp the high level methodology for approaching this type of problem

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this example, your random variables are discrete so it would behoove you to create a table. If $X=1$ with probability $\frac{1}{5}$ then we know $Y\in\{2,3,4,5\}$. If $X=2$ with probability $\frac{1}{5}$ then we know $Y\in\{3,4,5\}$. If $X=3$ with probability $\frac{1}{5}$ then we know $Y\in\{4,5\}$. If $X=4$ with probability $\frac{1}{5}$ then we know $Y=5$. If $X=5$ with probability $\frac{1}{5}$ then the urn is empty and so $Y=0$.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
X/ Y& Y=0 & Y=1 & Y=2 & Y=3 & Y=4 & Y=5\\ \hline
X=1 & 0& 0&\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{20}&\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{20}&\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{20}&\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{20}\\ \hline
X=2 & 0 & 0&0&\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{15}&\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{15}&\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{15}\\ \hline
X=3 & 0 & 0&0&0&\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{10}&\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{10}\\ \hline
X=4 &  0& 0&0&0&0&\frac{1}{5}\\ \hline
X=5 &  \frac{1}{5}& 0&0&0&0&0\\ \hline
\end{array}

You should check that the individual probabilities sum to $1$ (they do!). From here you should be able to find the desired probabilities.